# Можно ли просмотреть исходный код стандартных библиотек Java, Android на Андроиде

Tags: java, android, android-library, library

Мне сейчас необходимо, пока ноут в ремонте, просмотреть и понять, как написаны основные классы `Android` и `Java`. Как это сделать на андроиде? Там практически же текст.

Comment: Если проблема в том, что неудобно смотреть код через текстовый редактор, то скачайте какой-нибудь редактор кода из PlayMarket.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Можете воспользоваться сайтом *grepcode* (в таком случае для просмотра можно использовать любой мобильный браузер). Например, информацию по Java ищите [тут](http://grepcode.com/) , а по Android [тут](http://grepcode.com/project/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android).

Comment: А скачать jre и по файлам не получиться?

Comment: @ДмитрийБережной, а какой смысл?)